# Spring and jackson, how to disable FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS through @ResponseBody

Tags: spring, jackson

Is there a global configuration in spring that can disable spring FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS for all controller annotated with @ResponseBody?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can configure your object mapper when configuring `configureMessageConverters`

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = 
        new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
    return converter;
}
```

If you want to know how to do exactly in your application, please update your question with your configuration files (xml or java configs).

Here is a good [article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/customizing) how to customize message converters.

**Edit:** If you are using XML instead of Java configs, you can create a custom `MyJsonMapper` class extending `ObjectMapper` with custom configuration, and then use it as follows

```
public class MyJsonMapper extends ObjectMapper {    
        public MyJsonMapper() {
            this.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        }
}
```

In your XML:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>


<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.mycompany.example.MyJsonMapper" >
```

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, you can do this: `spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false`

Answer (score 83):

If you are using Spring Boot, you can set the following property in application.properties file.

`spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false`

Thanks to @DKroot for his valuable comment. But I believe this should be its own answer for others.

Comment: Good tip, but beware it wont' work with HAL, as Spring HATEOAS constructs its own object mapper.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/333

Answer (score 9):

cant find `spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false` in spring boot 2.2.5

I use this

```
@Configuration
public class SerializationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper().disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.. Thank you, propertie `spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false` never worked for me even with spring finding it

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spring Boot / JPA ,  you also have to observe if you are using

getOne (goes for jpa getReference ) for the findOne / enetiyManager.find(Clazz , id)

GetOne Relies on Persistence cached reference by ID that is designed to retrieve entity with only ID in it. Its use was mostly for indicating reference existed without the need to retrieve whole entity.

The find method is straight forward to persistence manager to obtain the persistent instance.

This second one will observe you annotation @JsonIgnore accordingly and will give you the expected result.

```
 // On entity...
 @JsonIgnore
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "foo")
 private List<Foo> fooCollection;

 // later on persistence impl
 entityManager.find(Caso.class, id);

 // or on serivce 
 casoRepository.findById(id); //...
```

Comment: Kudos. `@JsonIgnore` is better if you have to maintain an already existing app

Answer (score 0):

For me, the Issue was with typecasting from **org.json.JSONObject** object to **org.json.simple.JSONObject** and I solved it by parsing value from **org.json.JSONObject** and then cast it to use as **org.json.simple.JSONObject**

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
org.json.simple.JSONObject xmlNodeObj = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) parser.parse(XMLRESPONSE.getJSONObject("xmlNode").toString());
```