# disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS through xml

Tags: json, serialization, jackson

I have this exception in my application is caused somehow by the spring AOP Aspect that i introduced in my application.
It says that can not serialise an empty bean and it suggest to disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS.

can any one show me how to do that trough spring xml config file?
 The exception is:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor and
 no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: eu.europa.ec.digitb3.talentpool.web.shared.config.
UIConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e7a48923["callbacks"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.aop.framework
.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: eu.eur
opa.ec.digitb3.talentpool.web.shared.config.UIConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e7a48923["callbacks"])
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:238)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:161)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:202)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:338)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
        at eu.cec.digit.ecas.client.Client.processAlreadyAuthenticatedUser(Client.java:1293)
        at eu.cec.digit.ecas.client.Client.processFlowAlreadyAuthenticatedUser(Client.java:1281)
        at eu.cec.digit.ecas.client.Client.protectFlow(Client.java:830)
        at eu.cec.digit.ecas.client.Client.protect(Client.java:713)
        at eu.cec.digit.ecas.client.Client.doProtect(Client.java:694)
        at eu.cec.digit.ecas.client.Client.doProtect(Client.java:665)
        at eu.cec.digit.ecas.client.filter.EcasFilter.doFilter(EcasFilter.java:279)
        at eu.cec.digit.ecas.client.filter.MetaFilter.doFilter(MetaFilter.java:395)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3288)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1513)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor and no properties discovered to
create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: eu.europa.ec.digitb3.talentpool.web.shared.config.UIConfiguration$$EnhancerBySp
ringCGLIB$$e7a48923["callbacks"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:59)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:26)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serializeContents(ObjectArraySerializer.java:228)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serializeContents(ObjectArraySerializer.java:25)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ArraySerializerBase.serialize(ArraySerializerBase.java:57)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:114)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1887)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231)
        ... 43 more
```

Comment: The answer is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862483/spring-and-jackson-how-to-disable-fail-on-empty-beans-through-responsebody topic