# No serializer found for class java.util.logging.ErrorManager and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer

Tags: java, json, rest, serialization, spring-boot

I have a problem with serializing a response in REST application.

Here's quick snapshot of my code:
ResponseWrapper.class

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) 
public class ResponseWrapper {

     private User user;
     private Token token;
     private Authentication authentication;

     public ResponseWrapper(){}
     //setters and getters
}
```

Configuration.class

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode =    ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) 
public ResponseWrapper response() {
    return new ResponseWrapper();
}
```

}

In my implementation class i got a autowired variable:

```
@Autowired
ResponseWrapper response;
```

When i returning my response just like

```
return response;
```

i got a message

```
Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: No serializer found for class java.util.logging.ErrorManager and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.coig.prek.webservice.utils.wrappers.ResponseWrapper$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e771672["targetSource"]->org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource["beanFactory"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory["beanClassLoader"]->org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader["resources"]->org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot["context"]->org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext["logger"]->org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog["logger"]->java.util.logging.Logger["parent"]->java.util.logging.Logger["parent"]->java.util.logging.Logger["parent"]->java.util.logging.Logger["handlers"]->org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler["errorManager"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.util.logging.ErrorManager and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.coig.prek.webservice.utils.wrappers.ResponseWrapper$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e771672["targetSource"]->org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource["beanFactory"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory["beanClassLoader"]->org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader["resources"]->org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot["context"]->org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext["logger"]->org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog["logger"]->java.util.logging.Logger["parent"]->java.util.logging.Logger["parent"]->java.util.logging.Logger["parent"]->java.util.logging.Logger["handlers"]->org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler["errorManager"])
```

And I actually have no idea what I am doing wrong. I tried to `@JsonIgnore` annotation with `@JsonProperty`but it was no diffrence i working. So I am asking you, what I am doing wrong, that it won't serializable correctly?

If the description is not enough, sorry, I don't know what else I could write about this problem.

@Edit
I am returning response bean using ResponseEntity class

```
return new ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here, jackson is trying to serialize an empty object.
You need to configure jackson to avoid this thing:

jackson 1.x:

```
myObjectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
```

jackson 2.X

```
myObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
```

An example to do this thing in Spring can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862483/spring-and-jackson-how-to-disable-fail-on-empty-beans-through-responsebody)

Comment: The problem is that when i am doing that i got "Infinite recursion" for some reason. In other hand that serialized object is never empty.

Comment: Try to remove `Autowired` from respone instance.

Comment: But if I understand it corectly i will not be able to call a instance of that bean

Comment: I think response should be created by the code not by the container. So removing it should be good,