# Why do I need to include @JsonProperty with my RestController

Tags: jackson, spring-restcontroller

Rest Controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/rest/new-subscriptions")
public List<NewSubscriptionDTO> getNewSubscriptions() {
    NewSubscriptionDTO dto = new NewSubscriptionDTO();
    dto.setId("54");
    dto.setName("John Doe");
    return Arrays.asList(dto);
}
```

NewSubscriptionDTO:

```java
package dermatica.web.admin.rx;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class NewSubscriptionDTO implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

> no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception,
> disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

If I annotate the fields with @JsonProperty it work fine.

Is there a way for the serialization to work automatically without needing this annotation?

Comment: A few good suggestions here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367312/serializing-with-jackson-json-getting-no-serializer-found

Comment: Just following up, have you solved this issue yet or did you decide to leave the annotations?

Answer (score 0):

`@JsonProperty` auto-generates a getter/setter that Jackson uses to read/write to the fields during serialization/deserialization. Here are some alternative approaches:

- Provide your own public getters/setters for all fields
- Make the fields public, generally frowned upon, but if you're creating a simple DTO, that may be acceptable.
- Setting ObjectMapper Visibility for `FIELD` to `ANY` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367312/serializing-with-jackson-json-getting-no-serializer-found/8395924#8395924))
- Disable the `FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` exception (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862483/spring-and-jackson-how-to-disable-fail-on-empty-beans-through-responsebody/45175428#45175428))

Given that your DTO class has getters and setters, this should work without `@JsonProperty`. I wasn't able to reproduce the exact error message you showed, but here are some suggestions that may help:

- [Controller] Explicitly specify the method type as `GET`, either using `method = GET` or `@GetMapping` - not necessary, but it's good to be explicit
- [Controller] Make sure you annotate the controller class with `@RestController`, indicating the response is serialized to JSON and wrapped in an `HttpResponse` object.
- [DTO] You don't need to extend `Serializable` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457074/spring-mvc-should-my-domain-classes-implement-serializable-for-over-the-wire-t)).

The final controller would look like this:

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {

  @GetMapping(value = "/admin/rest/new-subscriptions")
  public List<MyDTO> getDTO() {
    MyDTO dto = new MyDTO();
    dto.setId("54");
    dto.setName("John Doe");
    return Collections.singletonList(dto);
  }
}
```

Response:

```
[{"id":"54","name":"John Doe"}]
```

Comment: The class has getters and setters but its still throwing the exception. The only way I can get it to serialize as json is if I use the @JsonProperty annotation.

Comment: @DD. I updated my answer to point out some possible issues with your controller code. Please try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: It didnt work....do I need to do something in Spring config to get Jackson to do this automatically?

Comment: @DD. I didn't need to do anything else to get it to work. Can you share the relevant parts of your POM/gradle file in your question indicating any spring/jackson libraries you're using and their versions?